# Typescript how to hint function name

Tags: typescript

How to type function names as strings? This pseudo code illustrates my question

```
const foo = () => null;
const bar = () => null;

interface Sth {
    caller: nameof foo | nameof bar
}
```

The above code generates following error:

`error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'bar'.`

this way this would be ok:

`const x: Sth = { caller: 'foo' }`

but this would error:

`const y: Sth = { caller: 'y' }`

[Typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20foo%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20null%3B%0D%0Aconst%20bar%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20null%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Sth%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20caller%3A%20foo.name%20%7C%20bar.name%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: Those are anonymous functions... Anonymous functions do not have a `name` property. I mean, those are anonymous function stored in a variables called `foo` and `bar`, but the functions themselves do not have a name.

Comment: This question is a mess. Not only it is hard to comprehend the meaning, there is no even OK formatting, this is disrespectful to readers.. You better have a new try asking new, better formed question.

Comment: What do you not understand? If you have some suggestions on formatting, feel free to edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody is looking for an answer, to achieve the above you need to make an object consisting of functions, and use it's keys to type hint the type using `keysof typeof`

```
const foo = () => null;
const bar = () => null;

const functions = { foo, bar };

interface HasCallerType {
    caller: keyof typeof functions
}

const a: HasCallerType = {
    caller: 'foo'
}
```

With this definition the following will error:

```
const b: HasCallerType = {
    caller: 'meh'
}
```

Here is link to test it in practice:

[Typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20foo%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20null%3B%0D%0Aconst%20bar%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20null%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20functions%20%3D%20%7B%20foo%2C%20bar%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20HasCallerType%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20caller%3A%20keyof%20typeof%20functions%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20a%3A%20HasCallerType%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20caller%3A%20'foo'%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20b%3A%20HasCallerType%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20caller%3A%20'meh'%0D%0A%7D)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time understanding what you are trying to accomplish here.

One one hand `foo` and `bar` are anonymous functions and anonymous functions do not have a name.... but lets imagine that you had done something like this:

```
function foo(a: number) {
  return a;
}

function bar(x: number) {
  return x + 1;
}
```

What do you expect interface `Sth` to look like exactly? Why do you care about the names of the functions at all?

Based on your last comment, I *think* that what you are trying to accomplish is this:

```
interface Sth {
    caller: 'foo' | 'bar'
}
```

Comment: Without the name of the function, the `caller` prop would need to be a string.
I'd like to limit string options to the function names. 
this way the following would be fine
const nar: Sth = {
  caller: 'foo'
}
but the following would error: 
const nar: Sth = {
  caller: 'xxx'
}

Comment: @Adam that context would be useful *in the question*. Also, it's hard to see how your answer helps at all with that. In this case you presumably also need to be able to access the function by string name, so having a mapping `const callers = { foo, bar }` would let you use `keyof callers` and `callers[caller]`.

Comment: I updated the question to flash out what I'd like to do better.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I tried your suggestion, and I don't think it's working: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20foo%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20null%3B%0D%0Aconst%20bar%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20null%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20callers%20%3D%20%7B%20foo%2C%20bar%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Sth%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20caller%3A%20keyof%20callers%0D%0A%7D

Comment: @Josep I know I can simply use hardcoded strings, I'd like to use function names directly though, to have one source of truth

Comment: @Adam that should be `keyof typeof callers`; `callers` is a value, not a type.

Comment: Perfect! That does it perfectly. This way i can have one export file and import the types based on function names. If you'd like to put it as an answer I will accept it. Thanks